# Browser back/next arrows when only HTML content change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, thymeleaf

I have created a main page (with header, sidebar and footer) for my web application and I change only the content of this page using element load:

```
<aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
        <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
            <li sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                <a onCLick="testAction('/test')">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span>Test</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</aside>

<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div id="main_content" class="content-wrapper"></div>
<footer class="main-footer"></footer>
<!-- Dashboard js -->
<script th:src="@{/static/assets/js/index.js?date=17102017}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in javascript I have:

```
function testAction(url){
    $("#main_content").load(url, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "error")
            $("#main_content").load("/404", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){              
            });
    });
}
```

In this way I load only the content of the page and not all the page as I did before this change (I used Thymeleaf Layout Dialect).
But I have a problem: now the url is the same for all the page since I change only the content and now the back/next button doesn't work. I tried with

```
window.history.pushState
```

but only change the url and with back press the content still the same. Do you have idea of how can I make these buttons work?Thanks
PS: if no embedded function exists I should use a list with the page history and load manually on next/back catch button

Comment: Why don't you use AngularJS's router: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09 ?

Comment: thanks for the advice, I read it right away

Comment: This's not correct pattern for developing angular application. You should make use of routing to navigate to different parts (views) of your angular app, you can use ngRoute or ui-router plugin libs

Comment: with angular I have to import all css and javascript in the main page?